# WiFi hotspot option disabled after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager

After a successful upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, the WiFi hotspot option became disabled and when I hover on it, it shows "**System policy prohibits use as a Hotspot**". I have tried changing the hotspot modes but the same problem persists.

Comment: The duplicate question was created but it has a solution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230690/wifi-hotspot-option-disabled-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by referring [Fix Wi-Fi Hotspot Not Working (Can not connect) in Ubuntu 18.04 | UbuntuHandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/10/fix-wi-fi-hotspot-not-working-ubuntu-18-04/)

> 1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on keyboard to bring up 'Enter a Command' box, then input `nm-connection-editor` and hit
>    <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    [image]
> 2. When the **'Network Connections'** window pops up, click on the bottom-left plus button to create a new connection.
>
>    [image]
> 3. In next window, select **Wi-Fi** from the drop-down box.
>
>    [image]
> 4. After clicked the 'Create…' button, do following settings in next window.
>
>    - Type connection name: whatever as you want (`Ji-laptop` in the case)
>    - Type SSID: whatever as you want (`ubuntu1804` in the case)
>    - Select Mode: **Hotspot**
>    - (Optional) Set password in Wi-Fi security tab. (WPA & WPA2 Personal in my case)
>
>    *Tip: you may disable ‘Automatically connect to this network when
>    it is available’ in General tab, or Wi-Fi hotspot auto-enabled in
>    every login.*
>    [image]
> 5. Finally in **Wi-Fi** Settings window, do:
>
>    - click the top-right menu and select **Connect to Hidden Network**…
>    - then choose connect to the previous created network.
>
>    [image]

Answer (score 13):

The button is also deactivated on my system after I upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04. And this is how I manage to enable my hotspot.

[image]

1. Click on **Connect to Hidden Network**

   [image]
2. Select **Hostpot** for the connection field.

   [image]
3. For me my hotspot network get automatically selected after that. And your finish by clicking on **connect**

Comment: @RKatana please accept the answer, this works as the best workaround

Answer (score 11):

Try switching to another settings tab and back to WiFi settings tab. That fixed it for me.

This has been reported on Launchpad as [Bug #1883425 “Various bugs in network part of GNOME settings” : Bugs : gnome-control-center package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1883425).

Answer (score 7):

I started Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and ran:

```
sudo gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Does this solves the problem regarding hotspots?

Comment: At least it gives you full control. Now you can edit and start hotspot. ( in combination with nm-connection-editor ). But I do not think that this is a final solution for a setting I configured at first in a user context. It is all a bit confusing. I would call it a work-around.

Comment: now the button is enabled and I can use the functionality properly, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Click on any other tab in the settings and then return back to wifi section. You'll get it back.

Comment: This actually works. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if other answers here are working or not but you might have to wait for the next release with the new network manager 1.22.10-1ubuntu3~build1 which has fixed the hotspot issue